# MongoDB won't connect to 127.0.0.1 on Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, macos, mongodb

I have a Mac running 10.8.2 and just installed mongodb running the `brew install mongodb` command. Everything seemed to be installed correctly. However when I run `mongo` to enter the shell I get the following error:

```
Alexander-Burgos-Collazos-MacBook:~ Alexander$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
connecting to: test
Wed Feb  6 19:44:59 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:91
exception: connect failed
```

I followed some threads around here but never got a clear and concise answer as to how to fix it. I entered `mongod` in the command terminal and it returned:

```
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

From there on everything I input does not return anything. I am confused as to how this really works.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/ In one terminal, start the mongo database with `mongod`. This process will not stop until you stop it as it's the database engine. In a new terminal window, `mongo` to start the shell. Go here then: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/

Comment: WiredPrairie thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

May be mongod not started.

For start manually use command:

```
/usr/local/opt/mongodb/mongod run --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

But brew has a lanchctl plist. You can run this command and mongodb launch at login:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

More about brew version mongodb:

```
brew info mongodb
```

More about mongod you can read in [manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongod/#mongod).

Answer (score 2):

Latest versions of Brew supports

`brew services start mongodb`

Answer (score 0):

My mongo installation been corrupted and uninstalling mongo and reinstall worked for me, following procedure may be helpful

Remove mongodb from /usr/local/Cellar
Remove mongod.conf files from /usr/local/etc
Remove mongodb data from /usr/local/var

verify there should not be database exist at: /usr/local/etc 
use command: cd /d
verify no process should be running:
ps aux | grep mongo

Reinstall mongo:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/